# Facebook App Page with Custom URL Scheme not linking

Tags: ios, facebook

Trying to set up ability to launch our app when 'Use App' button clicked in Facebook.

We've got the app installed with a custom url scheme, say `myapp`.
When we navigate to `myapp://` in Safari, it opens the app just fine.

But the 'Use App' button in Facebook is not linking to my app which is installed on the phone. Instead, it opens the website.

Below are the fields we've filled out. For `URL Scheme Suffix` field I have `myapp` as the value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This functionality - for whatever reason - is only visible when editing the actual Facebook page, not the app settings. See screenshot below

[image]